# How to Prevent Image and Content Theft from our Website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Are there any ways to prevent image and content theft from our website?

As we all know, we can save as images/contents on a website, and even check the source code. I'm worried about some people stealing our content, and they may modify images and display them on their websites. They may even modify and re-use our source code.

Is there any solution which can prevent theft from our website?

Comment: Ah the age old question. I don't think you can, there will always be a way to steal an image if someone really wants to. You can prevent right click with javascript but that won't do much.  You could encode content. Go to google and look at the page source.

Answer (score 4):

You can watermark images but that's probably not ideal for every image you'd have on a website. Other than that, no, there is no way to prevent someone who's determined enough to steal images or any other content from a website. With images they can always just screenshot the page and crop it if they're that desperate.

Minifying code is a best practice since it reduces the size of files the user downloads when visiting your site. It also has the added benefit of making code harder to read at first glance - but it is trivial to use an IDE or similar to reformat it again.

You should make sure that you have licensing clearly displayed in source code and that you're vigilant with copyright complaints.

Answer (score 2):

You could prevent right-click but as you say anyone can use the inspector.

For the images you can try adding a watermark, which would dissuade almost anyone from the trouble of trying to edit it out in photoshop.

To protect your code look into code minification... it's really for slashing the size down, but prevents people from reading your code... although anyone can also just copy and paste it into an un-minifier.

Answer (score 2):

No. There are a few things you can do in the HTML and JavaScript to make it a bit more difficult but anyone determined can circumvent them without much trouble.

Instead, make sure your copyright/licensing is watertight in case you need to sue anyone. Essentially this is a legal issue, not a technical one.

N.B. If you are selling content, make sure it's protected by authentication so that only those who have paid for it can access it (and even then, set strict terms and conditions / copyright protection to limit legitimate re-use). If you need people to preview that content, then provide low-res/watermarked/abbreviated (depending on the type of media)  versions of the content in the public area of your site so that it has low/no value if copied.

For source code, there are techniques to obfuscate it, but they are generally reversible. Obviously this only applies to JavaScript. Any server-side code is not visible to the end user.

Answer (score 1):

As others said the only way is to add a watermark on them, but it is usually not possible. Not about programming but the thing comes to my mind is Steganography; you can hide embed text or your logo inside your image then when someone uses your image might request copyright maybe... But it'll probably be just a fantasy.